# handle return/enter key pressed event in virtual keyboard in Blackberry 10 app

Tags: blackberry-10, enter, virtual-keyboard

I wanted to override the functionality pressed enter/return key in virtual key that is popped up when user taps on a TextField.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

---

EDIT 1 :

I am currently using the following code:

```
passwordTextField->input()->setSubmitKey(SubmitKey::Connect);
connect(passwordTextField->input(), SIGNAL(submitted()), this, SLOT(onDoneButtonPressed()));
```

still the slot is not getting called. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The `connect()` returns `false`. What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would connect the signal http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__abstracttextcontrol.html#function-textchanged-text to a slot that performs the action you want. You may also wish to change the following properties on the TextField:

- Submit Key
- Submit Key Focus

Comment: I have connected the signal `void textChanged (QStringtext)` with a slot using this `connect(passwordTextField, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(enterButtonPressEventHandler(QString)));` but the slot is not getting called when I press the enter/return key.

Comment: In projects where I use it, it does work. It is going to be difficult to solve your problem with so little information.